# JSF Validation for INLINE

Tags: jsf

hibernate-validator 4.0.2.Final.jar in my classpath.

inline validation:

```
<tr:inputText label="Bin" id="Bin"
value="#{vinController.vin}"  required="true" size="20">
<f:validateLength minimum="10" maximum="17"></f:validateLength>
</tr:inputText>
```

Trinidad-config.xml:

```
<client-validation>INLINE</client-validation>
```

This isn't working the way I intended it to.

Comment: _This isn't working the way I intended it to._ Could you reveal what this means?

Comment: When a local submit button is pressed, this should result in the validation taking place.  As is, nothing happens but a  quick reload to the project home page.  Which is not the desired behavior.  I was expecting the <f:validateLength> validation to execute on the value in the inputText field, but as I mentioned it doesn't.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- Vin: Validation Error: Length is less than allowable minimum of '10'

Comment: the above comment is coming from the server:log when I enter a value less than 10, which is good that it at least notices that it's not working, but still no message in the app itself

Answer (score 1):

Add a `h:messages` tag somewhere in your facelet to display messages:

```
<h:messages/>
```

This will display all messages.

Or alternatively:

```
<h:message for="Bin"/>
```

will show only messages for the component with `id="Bin"`.

Comment: I added teh above <h:messages/> and the <h:message for="Bin"/> Still no message showing.  It's puzzling